How to return a count of consecutive weekday dates in R
I have a dataset which includes itinerary, service provider, dates, and a boolean flag. I am trying to find out which itineraries have had at least three sequential weekdays with flag = 1, and I need to be able to also see how many times they've had at least three sequential days with that flag status [Thursday, Friday, Monday, should count as 3 days in sequence for this purpose]. That said, see below for generating a minimum working dataframe.
Minimum Working Data
# Generate sequential dates and remove weekends
days <- rep(seq(as.Date('2024-03-01'), as.Date('2024-03-14'), '1 day'), 1, each = 10)
days <- days[!weekdays(days) %in% c('Saturday','Sunday')]

# Create minimum working dataset
# No, my service providers are not actually three-letter-agencies :)
set.seed(1337)

df <- tibble(
  itinerary = rep(101:110, 10),
  service = rep(c("CIA", "CIA", "FBI", "FBI", "FBI", "FBI", "NSA", "NSA", "CIA", "FBI"), 10),
  date = days,
  flag = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE))

> head(df)
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  itinerary service date        flag
      <int> <chr>   <date>     <dbl>
1       101 CIA     2024-03-01     1
2       102 CIA     2024-03-01     0
3       103 FBI     2024-03-01     1
4       104 FBI     2024-03-01     0
5       105 FBI     2024-03-01     1
6       106 FBI     2024-03-01     1

What I've Tried
As for what I've tried- I've used a combination of a lot of answers I've found on Stack (1, 2, 3) and have so far ended up with the following [possibly intermediary step]:
df_working <- df %>% 
  group_by(itinerary, service, flag) %>% 
  mutate(grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(date) != 1))) %>% 
  group_by(grp, .add = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise(
    len = n(),
    start_date = first(date),
    end_date = last(date),
    .groups = 'drop'
  )


> head(df_working)
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  itinerary service  flag   grp   len start_date end_date  
      <int> <chr>   <dbl> <int> <int> <date>     <date>    
1       101 CIA         0     1     1 2024-03-05 2024-03-05
2       101 CIA         0     2     1 2024-03-08 2024-03-08
3       101 CIA         0     3     2 2024-03-11 2024-03-12
4       101 CIA         1     1     1 2024-03-01 2024-03-01
5       101 CIA         1     2     1 2024-03-04 2024-03-04
6       101 CIA         1     3     2 2024-03-06 2024-03-07

The problem is that 2024-03-01 and 2024-03-04 in rows 4 and 5 are a Friday and Monday respectively, and I want to treat those two dates as consecutive for this purpose. The output I want should be closer to the following.
Desired Output
> head(df_working_ideal)
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  itinerary service  flag   grp   len start_date end_date  
      <int> <chr>   <dbl> <int> <int> <date>     <date>    
1       101 CIA         0     1     1 2024-03-05 2024-03-05
2       101 CIA         0     2     1 2024-03-08 2024-03-08
3       101 CIA         0     3     2 2024-03-11 2024-03-12
4       101 CIA         1     1     2 2024-03-01 2024-03-01
5       101 CIA         1     2     2 2024-03-06 2024-03-07

I believe there's something I need to adjust with my mutate() call, and I've tried adding in various operators from lubridate, but nothing seems to work the way I want it/expect it to. What am I missing?
EDIT
I realized that counting weekdays alone isn't exactly what I want. Sometimes we're not running anything on a given weekday because of release days... So, I think what I need is to count the number of consecutive dates from a list of dates within the full dataset, as I won't have any data/dates from days where we didn't provide service.
Further EDIT:
I think I've found a possible solution, but I think there has to be a better way than this?
# Find all dates in the data set
days_unique <- unique(days) %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  arrange() %>% rename(date = value) %>% mutate(seq = row_number())

# Use that new date sequence for df man
df_test <- df %>% 
  left_join(days_unique, join_by(date)) %>% 
  group_by(itinerary, service, flag) %>% 
  mutate(grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(seq)) != 1)) %>% 
  group_by(grp, .add = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(cons_days = ifelse(seq == first(seq), last(seq) - seq +1, 0)) %>% 
  summarise(
    cons_days = max(cons_days),
    start_date = first(date),
    end_date = last(date),
    .groups = 'drop'
  )

> head(df_test)
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  itinerary service  flag   grp cons_days start_date end_date  
      <int> <chr>   <dbl> <int>     <dbl> <date>     <date>    
1       101 CIA         0     0         1 2024-03-05 2024-03-05
2       101 CIA         0     1         3 2024-03-08 2024-03-12
3       101 CIA         1     0         2 2024-03-01 2024-03-04
4       101 CIA         1     1         2 2024-03-06 2024-03-07
5       101 CIA         1     2         2 2024-03-13 2024-03-14
6       102 CIA         0     0         2 2024-03-01 2024-03-04

I believe this may have solved my problem, but I'm open to a less fiddly or more robust way of doing this!

Hello @Morrigan, if you're using sample() on your data, please remember to set.seed() for reprodutibility' sake.

@AdrianoMello Thank you for the reminder! I'll edit my question and outputs now with a set.seed() call added.

Here's one way to check if all days of an unique itinerary-service-flag group (ordered by starting date) are consecutive week days. Hope it helps your exploration.
# library(tidyverse)
# ------------------

new_df <- df %>% 
  arrange(itinerary, service, date, flag) %>% 
  mutate(id = consecutive_id(itinerary, service, flag)) %>% 
  summarise(
    .by = c(itinerary, service, flag, id),
    start_date = min(date),
    end_date = max(date),
    week_days = list(keep(seq.Date(from = min(date), to = max(date), by = "days"), \(x) wday(x) %in% 2:6)),
    n_days = map_int(week_days, \(x) length(x)),
    check = if_else(n_distinct(date) == n_days & n_days >= 3, TRUE, FALSE),
    week_days = str_flatten_comma(simplify(map(week_days, \(x) format(x, "%a-%d"))))) %>% 
  relocate(week_days, .after = last_col())

The output:
#    n_days: number of expected week days between start-end dates
#     check: TRUE if number of real week days between start-end dates
#            is equal to the expected n_days and equal-or-bigger-than 3
# week_days: expected week days between start-end dates (for visual inspection)
#            instead of relocate() you can select(-week_days)

    > new_df
# A tibble: 52 × 9
   itinerary service  flag    id start_date end_date   n_days check week_days                             
       <int> <chr>   <dbl> <int> <date>     <date>      <int> <lgl> <chr>                                 
 1       101 CIA         1     1 2024-03-01 2024-03-04      2 FALSE sex-01, seg-04                        
 2       101 CIA         0     2 2024-03-05 2024-03-05      1 FALSE ter-05                                
 3       101 CIA         1     3 2024-03-06 2024-03-07      2 FALSE qua-06, qui-07                        
 4       101 CIA         0     4 2024-03-08 2024-03-12      3 TRUE  sex-08, seg-11, ter-12                
 5       101 CIA         1     5 2024-03-13 2024-03-14      2 FALSE qua-13, qui-14                        
 6       102 CIA         0     6 2024-03-01 2024-03-04      2 FALSE sex-01, seg-04                        
 7       102 CIA         1     7 2024-03-05 2024-03-07      3 TRUE  ter-05, qua-06, qui-07                
 8       102 CIA         0     8 2024-03-08 2024-03-14      5 TRUE  sex-08, seg-11, ter-12, qua-13, qui-14
 9       103 FBI         1     9 2024-03-01 2024-03-06      4 TRUE  sex-01, seg-04, ter-05, qua-06        
10       103 FBI         0    10 2024-03-07 2024-03-07      1 FALSE qui-07                                
# ℹ 42 more rows

